# How to get the domain name in JSTL?

Tags: jstl, jsp-tags

In my jsp, I want to get the current domain name. How can I get this using jstl ?

Eg., if the user is browsing through the site 'www.somesite.com', I want to display that domain 'www.somesite.com' in jsp. How to do that ?

Can we get it from the request object ?

Or, is there any other way ?

Comment: Have you checked the API for the request object? Have you done any research at all?

Answer (score 3):

```
<c:out value="${pageContext.request.serverName}" />
```